# AngularJS: invalid input is not styled as invalid until I click on the input field and click out of it

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am setting input field to invalid from javascript like this:

```
$scope.formName.fieldName.$setValidity("string", false);
```

This is working, but it affects the view only after clicking in a input field and then clicking out of it.

How can I change it in order to see the invalid field immediatelly?

Comment: There's not enough information here, for example what is "string" targeting? 'required'?

Comment: That does not matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to attach an `ng-change="checker(model)"` to your input field. Then just apply an `ng-class` to it to check for `formName.fieldName.$error.string` (since you put string as the error key) or you can also do `formName.fieldName.$invalid && !formName.fieldName.$pristine`

I've attached this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzEywK) for you to play around with and see how to apply an invalid class on the field without having to lose focus on it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. ng-class="{'invalid': formName.fieldName.$error.string}" was working. I accept this answer but I have solved it differently: $scope.formName.$setSubmitted(); also sets the invalid style to the invalid fields.